# Combine rows into a list in PrestoSQL

Tags: presto, trino

Currently, my table has three different fields, `id1`, `id2` and `actions`. `action` is of type string. For example, my table looks something like the table given below:

```
id1   |   id2  |   actions
---------------------------
"a1"      "a2"     "action1"
"b1"      "b2"     "action2"
"a1"      "a2"     "action3"
```

If the values of `id1` and also the values`id2` are same for any number of rows, I want to combine those rows so that the `actions` field becomes a list of string. If none of the rows have same values for `id1` and same values for `id2`, I want to still convert the `actions` fields as a list but only with one string. For example, the output of the query should look something like the following:

```
id1   |   id2  |   actions
---------------------------
"a1"      "a2"     ["action1", "action3"]
"b1"      "b2"     ["action2"]
```

I know some basics of Presto and can join columns based on conditions but was not sure if this can be achieved with query. If this can be achieved, what is a good approach to move forward with the implementation of this logic?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try using `ARRAY_JOIN` with `ARRAY_AGG`:

```
SELECT
    id1,
    id2,
    ARRAY_JOIN(ARRAY_AGG(actions), ',') actions
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    id1,
    id2;
```

Comment: `ARRAY_JOIN(ARRAY_AGG(` this changes the order.  Do you know how to solve it?, In this question for a1 I want to maintain the order so the contact should be `action1,action2` But many times Im getting the misplaced order like `action2,action1`

Comment: If you like to keep the order please refer to `array_agg(x ORDER BY y DESC)`

Comment: @Vision that is truly golden, many thank you's!

Answer (score 2):

If you want the result as an array you can use flatten instead of array_join:

```
select   
    id1,  id2,   flatten(array_agg(actions)) as actions  
from table  
group by id1, id2
```